# Has there been an interrogative word to ask for a quantity or amount?

Tags: old-english, questions

English uses *how much/many* to ask for an amount or a quantity. Has there been an [interrogative word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word) in Old, Middle, or Modern English to convey the meaning of *how much/many* (i.e., an equivalent to the Spanish *cuánto* or the French *combien*)?

Comment: I don't get it, 'how much' doesn't work? Or do you mean a -single- word? Does it have to be an etymologically 'wh-' word too?

Comment: This question is derived from one that I asked in [Spanish Language and Usage](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/578/128). I'm just curious about the lack or a single-word quantity interrogative in English. I know that _how much_ and _how many_ presently serve the same purpose as the Spanish _cuánto_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert, but I think the Old English word [hwæt](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hw%C3%A6t) had [a broad range of meaning and applicability](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=words%20interrogative%20%22old%20english%22%20oe%20%22how%20much%22&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC8QFjAC&url=http://www.isle-linguistics.org/resources/walkden2011.pdf&ei=YhLPTuvFMIOl8gPR9KgH&usg=AFQjCNGxcw1JCAo9EPrKR40U5CohPsEvFA&sig2=V52H9_vrtzQvJSwgWuIZEQ&cad=rjt), which did actually include *how much*.

Comment: As George Walkden reminds us, ‘hwæt’ is best known for being the first word of ‘Beowulf’, where it is normally understood to be used simply to attract listeners’ attention: ‘lo!’ ‘behold!’.  The suggestion that it means ‘How much (we have heard of the might of the nation-kings of the Spear-Danes)’ is ingenious, but even if it can bear that interpretation, it’s a big leap to claim it as an Old English interrogative, similar to modern Spanish ‘cuánto?’ or modern French ‘combien?’

Comment: I didn't read the whole of Walkden's paper that I linked to (it's a bit too technical for me), but he does actually give "how much" as one potential paraphrasing. I seem to recall that *all* English **"wh- words"** derive from a single generic "interrogative", so mostly likely it's as @Mahnax says - either there isn't an equivalent to *combien*, or it's *hwæt*.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you want English; but other than FumbleFingers' answer, I don't think there is one. Latin uses *quantus* for *how much.*