# Single word for "how many"

Tags: abbreviations, old-english

Is there a way to say "how many" in a single word? (even something in Old English should be good enough)

Comment: Can you give an example of a sentence where you would use the word ?

Comment: It's not necessarily a sentence, I'm translating this website that ellaborates further on [the five W's of journalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Ws) and uses the words as url slugs.  Having a single word instead of two would make it easier to tell from simply 'how' and keep it closer to the concept (especially as there are common single words for it in other languages).

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49546/has-there-been-an-interrogative-word-to-ask-for-a-quantity-or-amount)?

Comment: I missed that post, although I did a search first, but the accepted answer doesn' seem to fit too well - `hwæt` looks like just an older form of `what`

Comment: I don't see the reason for using an obsolete term, which you might have in Old English, instead of a two-word expression which everyone will understand. What's wrong with: How many/much/often/long (or) how + adjective?

Comment: It's really not uncommon for URL slugs to have more than one word. The URL for this very question looks perfectly fine with `how-many`

Comment: Thanks for the typo. I answered that question just above - it's a technical use that mainly aims to be visually distinct from simply `how`. Url slugs are seldom read, rather perceived, while single words are much easier to be told apart from the joint ones. In this case, `howmany` may even be subconsciously seen as a sort of subordinate to `how`, which is simply not true.
I won't mind if indeed there is no word for it whatsoever, though :D

Comment: Latin [**quotiens**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=quotiens&la=latin) is *how often?* and *how many times?*

Comment: @Tushar Ray
I know that and I'll probably end up simply using it. Still, not being uncommon is not a primary concern ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real  interrogative word for how many. Some suggestions that possibly may be applied:

1. [count](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/count)
2. [volume](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/volume)
3. [amount](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/amount)
4. [quantity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quantity)
5. [number](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/number)
6. [size](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/size)
7. [dose](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dose)
8. [lot](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lot)
9. [parcel](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/parcel)

Hope this helps. A bit.

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/

Comment: Thanks. And congrats on the courage of a straight "no, there isn't" instead of "umm, you really wouldn't need that" ;)